# mongo-spark connector reading different number of documents from a collection every time

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, sbt, connector

I am using mongo-spark connector to create an rdd in scala. I have added the following in built.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

Followinf is my sparkconf:

```
val sparkConf = new `SparkConf().setAppName("stanfordner").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1g").set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/").set("spark.mongodb.input.database", "db").set("spark.mongodb.input.collection", "coll")`
```

I have tried creating an rdd from mongo collection using:

```
val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB()
```

`val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)` 
But every time I run the code, I am getting an rdd with different number of documents. I don't understand why is this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are changing the underlying collection (adding or deleting documents) then each RDD may well return a different number of documents.  How are you checking the number of documents in an RDD?

Comment: println(rdd.count()) . I am not changing the collection. Mongo query shows same count each time.

Comment: That could be indicative of an issue with the Partitioner - which partitioner are you using?  Either way sounds like a bug - file a ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK if you could provide a test case that  reproduces the error then that would be helpful.

Comment: I thought it had to do with the connector but it seems it's not. I tried another way of reading mongo by doing this val config = new Configuration()
config.set("mongo.job.input.format","com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat")
config.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db.coll")
val keyClassName = classOf[Object]
val valueClassName = classOf[BSONObject]
val inputFormatClassName = classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat]
val iprdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config,inputFormatClassName,keyClassName,valueClassName)
println(iprdd.count()). But this is also giving different counts